# Simple Hibernate Error - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 - Unknown Column

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am stuck in a spring-hibernate application. I am getting following error. Please help.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="milestones")
public class MileStone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int milestoneid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="milestone",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) 
    @BatchSize(size=2)
    private List<Merchant_MileStone> merchantMileStones = new ArrayList<Merchant_MileStone>();

     public List<Merchant_MileStone> getMerchantMileStones() {
        return merchantMileStones;
    }

     public void setMerchantMileStone(List<Merchant_MileStone> merchantMileStones) {
        this.merchantMileStones = merchantMileStones;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="completed_milestones")
public class Completed_MileStone {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    private int merchant_ms_id;



    @ManyToOne 
    private MileStone milestone;

    public MileStone getMilestone() {
        return milestone;
    }

    public void setMilestone(MileStone milestone) {
        this.milestone = milestone;
    }

}
```

and at this line

```
MileStone mileStone=(MileStone) session.get(MileStone.class,1);
```

I am getting this error -

```
Hibernate: select milestone0_.milestoneid as mileston1_1_0_, merchantmi1_.milestone_milestoneid as mileston2_1_1_, merchantmi1_.merchant_ms_id as merchant1_0_1_, merchantmi1_.merchant_ms_id as merchant1_0_2_, merchantmi1_.milestone_milestoneid as mileston2_0_2_ from milestones milestone0_ left outer join completed_milestones merchantmi1_ on milestone0_.milestoneid=merchantmi1_.milestone_milestoneid where milestone0_.milestoneid=?
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'merchantmi1_.milestone_milestoneid' in 'field list'
```

What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong in the code (except the lack of respect of standard naming conventions). You simply need to read the exception to see what is wrong: *Unknown column 'merchantmi1_.milestone_milestoneid'*. Your `completed_milestones` table doesn't have a column `milestone_milestoneid` that it should have, given how you mapped the ManyToOne association with milestone in the Completed_MileStone entity.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Thanks. It worked.So it expects some column name in auto generated query of join ?

Comment: A Completed_MileStone is associated with a MileStone. This association has to be stored somewhere in the database. The default mapping for a ManyToOne is to use a join column. You could specify the name of this column using a JoinColumn annotation. If you don't, JPA specifies a default name to be used.